# I get error message 'Version in "./docker-compose.yaml" is invalid - it should be a string.'

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I get this error message when i run command - `docker-comose up`

> ERROR: Version in "./docker-compose.yaml" is invalid - it should be a string.

My docker-compose file:

```yaml
    version: 3.9
    services:
      backend:
        build: .
        ports:
          - 8080:8080
        volumes:
          - ./:app
        depends_on:
          - db
      db:
        image: mysql:8
        restart: always
        environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: ambassador
          MYSQL_USER: root
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        volumes:
          - ./storage/dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
```

Comment: Is there more to the error, maybe naming a specific line or service?  The first `volumes:` block doesn't seem to have an absolute container path on the right-hand side of the `:`, but it also looks like if it worked correctly, it'd hide all of the work that's done in the Dockerfile.  I frequently recommend deleting `volumes:` blocks like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is quite clear here:

> Version in "./docker-compose.yaml" is invalid - it should be a string.

The `version` is specified as a number but should be a string, i.e.:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
```

Without explicit quotes the `yaml` parser will try to infer the type of the specified value. In this case `3.9` looks like a floating point number so the parser will parse it as a number - but the `docker-compose` specification requires it to be a string; so you have to explicitly quote it here.

Same goes e.g. for the values `true` and `false`: without explicit quoting the `yaml` parser will parse these as boolean values, throwing an error if they are used at places where a string value is expected.